# Warning when declaring pom dependency for servlet 3.1.0 in Spring 4.3.2

Tags: spring, maven

I use `Spring` 4.3.2.RELEASE , `Hibernate` 5.2.2.Final , `Maven` 4.0.0 and `STS` 3.8.1.RELEASE

I want to integrate `Hibernate` with `Spring` , I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration). In the tutorial it is mentioned for the `Java Servlet and JSP dependencies` this dependency :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The problem is that I got a warning when I copied this dependency : `The POM for javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:3.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available`

So how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't have a warning with this dependency. Do you have specific repositories or mirrors in Maven's settings.xml or in the pom.xml?

Comment: what do you mean by mirror ?

Comment: In Maven Central the servlet-api arifact is complete: http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/

Comment: settings.xml accepts a notion of mirror (an XML element really in settings.xml). Such mirror can be set if you're using an enterprise repository such as Nexus. Figured this could cause an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at you repository to see the content of the folder M2_REPO/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/.

The warning means that you probably have a jar inside but no POM. There was probably an issue when downloading that dependency since it is available in [Maven Central Repository](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/).

You can try to:

1. re-compile your project with `-U` option to force Maven to update
2. re-compile your project after deleting folder `M2_REPO/javax/servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/`.

Comment: there is a pom file there: `javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom`

Comment: Nothing related to Spring, but with Maven. By default it's in folder ~/.m2/repository

Comment: how to recompile the project with -U ? sorry but i am new to spring and maven stuff

Comment: If you have a pom to declare you dependencies, it means that you use maevn to compile. So type `mvn compile -U` in your project folder.

Comment: where is the executable of maven because i got error on command line that mvn is not recognized

Comment: So I guess your are using built Maven inside eclipse. You can right click on the project a select Maven, update project